# how to obtain an ordered list of coredata managed objects via accessing them via a relationship?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsset

How to obtain an ordered list of coredata managed objects via accessing them via a relationship?

That is:

- have the following entities: LIST, LIST_ITEM (includes an 'Order' field), and ITEM.
- assume that I have already fetched the list I want to work with
- I can then use the coredata relationships to get the LIST_ITEMS via using the relationship: e.g. "list1.listItems", and then for each of these LIST_ITEMS I can get the ITEM ("listItem1.item")

But if I really just want, from the LIST, an ordered list of ITEMS from the list, based on the "Order" field in the LIST_ITEM, what is the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the items returned by the relationship using an NSSortDescriptor just as you would in a regular fetch request.  For example:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortedListItems =  [list1.listItems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

The key method here is [`[NSSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSet/sortedArrayUsingDescriptors%3a)

Comment: so Alex this would give the sorted list of LIST_ITEM's back correct?  and then to get the Array of ITEM's which I'm after I would then need to programmatically create this array myself?

Comment: ok - thank Alex - but just to double checks, there's no neat way of avoiding that last programmatic step (i.e. using CoreData itself) that you know of?

Comment: Other than using a NSFetchRequest from scratch, no.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I understand the question correctly, but I think the best way to get lists from CoreData is create a compoun predicate and then search for items that way. For example if I am looking for only Events (entity) on a certain day, for a specific User (another entity). Then I can create an NSFetchRequest for the Event entry and specify and NSPredicate in the form of (user.name==%@) AND (event.date==%@) specifying the user's name and date

Comment: thanks - so I guess you're implying it may not be worth trying to use the relationships as they are a bit limiting then in terms of anything but the rudimentary return of items at the other end of the relationship?